# Get image height and width in centemeters

Tags: vb.net, image, size, photoshop

When I drag an image into Photoshop and go to "image size" I can see the size in cm (eg: 80X30 cm) In Windows 7, the only details you can see about the image regarding size is pixels and resolution. Is there a way in VBNET to get the image height and width in centimeters?

Comment: Maybe this'll help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/314a4e86-6d9b-4e76-8f09-6978f29b9818/get-real-image-size-in-centimeters?forum=winforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually one Pixel =  0.264583 Millimeter.
There is a difference between Dots Per Inch (DPI) and Device-Independent Pixel(DIPs)

[DPI and Device-Independent Pixels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684173(v=vs.85).aspx)

Best Regards

Comment: If you're using DPI, then you can try `pixels * 25,4 / dpi-value = result in mm`